# iPhone frame rate drops when rotation CCLayer 90 degrees with cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, rotation, frame-rate, cclayer

I am finished my cocos2d project, which uses the accelerometer to rotate the current CCLayer for a particular game mechanic.  I've always noticed a 10-15 fps drop of which I couldn't find and decided to take look now.  I thought it would have something to do with iterating over objects but it doesn't.

The drop occurs when the CCLayer is not rotated at 90/270 degrees, so as it approaches 0 degrees I lose 10 - 15 frames...super annoying.

I don't use the CCLayer for anything unusual, does anyone have any idea?

TL; DR: fps drops when CCLayer is rotated 90 degrees...Why?

Comment: are you setting the rotation in the accelerometer method? Don't, make  a scheduler, that checks some instance variables (you set them in the accelerometer method), you scheduler could run 30 times a second, and would still rotate smoothly, but would happen alot less frequently in the game tick, giving you more fps perhaps